# Convert array of locations into two separate variables of origins and destinations

Tags: php, arrays

Been beating on trying to get this to work for too long, asking for help.

I have an array of locations and I need them broken into two different strings/arrays so that I can pass them to the google maps api.

```
    [locations] => Array
    (
            [0] => 111 Some street
            [1] => 222 Some street
            [2] => 333 Some street
            [3] => 444 Some street
            [4] => 555 Some street
    )
```

What I need to end up having is:

```
$origin = '111 Some street|222 Some street|333 Some street|444 Some street';
$destination = '222 Some street|333 Some street|444 Some street|555 Some street';
```

There will not always be the same exact amount of locations in the array, sometimes just two, sometimes, perhaps dozens of locations.

Thanks... I got stuck on how to solve this.

Comment: `$origin = $destination = $locations; array_pop($origin); $origin = implode('|', $origin); array_shift($destination); $destination = implode('|', $destination); `

Comment: woot, thanks Mark! that is not even close to the direction I was going...

Comment: `$origins = join('|', array_slice($locations, 0, -1)); $destinations = join('|', array_slice($locations, 1));`